SIPSorcery: how to record ALL conversation (incoming and outgoing audio)
I am investigating SipSorcery Library for .NET and I need to record ALL audio inside conversation.
These examples:
https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/SIPExamples/RecordCall
https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery/tree/master/examples/SIPExamples/RecordIncomingCall
are recording only received audio, but not outgoing audio.
Is it a way to record both things in same File (o stream)?
Thanks.
